# __getattr__ doesn't work with __enter__ -> AttributeError

Tags: python

I would like to use `with` on an object that uses `__getattr__` to redirect calls.
Howerver, this does not seem to work with the method `__enter__`

Please consider the following, simplified code to reproduce the error:

```
class EnterTest(object):
    def myenter(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == '__enter__':
            return self.myenter

enter_obj = EnterTest()
print getattr(enter_obj, '__enter__')

with enter_obj:
    pass
```

Output:

```
<bound method EnterTest.myenter of <__main__.EnterTest object at 0x00000000021432E8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    with enter_obj:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Why doesn't it fall back to `__getattr__` since `__enter__` does not exist on the object?

Of course, I could make it work if I just create an `__enter__` method and redirect from there instead, but I'm wondering why it doesn't work otherwise.

My python version is the following:

```
C:\Python27\python27.exe 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Once I fix your `__exit__` call (it takes four arguments, not one), this code works fine for me in 2.6.4.

Comment: (Tangental: even in simple example code, be sure to `raise AttributeError` from `__getattr__`, or you'll be inviting headaches on yourself and others.)

Comment: Wich version of python do you use ? Works fine for me with both 2.6 and 3. Your __exit__ header should be def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback), but that's something else.

Comment: Oh right, the `__exit__`...
C:\Python27\python27.exe 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
@Glenn: you mean because I only return something if name is `__enter__`?

Comment: Hmm... When I run it with 2.6 I don't get an error either.

Comment: This works with Python 2.5, 2.6 and 3.1, but not with 2.7 and 3.2.  Probably a bug introduced with the code for nested context managers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to upstream, this working was a bug in 2.6 which was "fixed" in 2.7.  The short answer is that methods like `__enter__` are looked up on the class, not on the object.

The documentation for this obscure behavior is at http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel#specialnames: `x[i] is roughly equivalent to ... type(x).__getitem__(x, i) for new-style classes`.

You can see this behavior with other special methods:

```
class foo(object):
    def __iadd__(self, i):
        print i
a = foo()
a += 1

class foo2(object):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        print key
        raise AttributeError
b = foo2()
b += 1

class foo3(object):
    pass
def func(self, i):
    print i
c = foo3()
c.__iadd__ = func
c += 1
```

The first works; the second two don't.  Python 2.6 didn't conform to this behavior for `__enter__` and `__exit__`, but 2.7 does.  http://bugs.python.org/issue9259

That said, it's painfully inconsistent that these methods can't be handled dynamically like any other attributes can.  Similarly, you can't instrument accesses to these methods with `__getattribute__` like you can any other method.  I can't find any intrinsic design logic to this.  Python is normally very consistent, and this is a fairly unpleasant wart.

Comment: FWIW, the rationale I suspect is behind this is performance; doing a full attribute lookup on `__enter__` is probably insignificant, but it likely matters a lot more for methods like `__add__`.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of python do you use? It seems to be an old bug. Look at [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/python-bugs-list@python.org/msg09286.html). Your code works with `Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12)` with fixed `def __exit__(self, *args):`.

Comment: I had found that bug via Google, but since I was using a later version it didn't occur to me to test it with a different version.  
I've updated my original post with the version information.